# change active state of flipswitch jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile

I am trying to save the value of a flipswitch and after reload the webapp, the option with the same value as the status has should be active. I.e. if you select `<option id="v2" value="0">OFF</option>`, the cookie `status` have the value 0 and after reloading the page the flipswitch should show `OFF`.

Now after every reload the first option is always selected automatically and with that the value too. How can I change that?

**my flipswitch:**

```
<select id="status" name="status" data-role="flipswitch">
  <option id="v1" value="1">ON</option>
  <option id="v2" value="0">OFF</option>


</select>
```

**my php snippet:**

```
    $t = time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 1000;
        setcookie("status", $_POST['status'], $t);
```

**my own try:**

```
function state () {
 var statuse = <?php echo $_COOKIE['status']; ?>;

 if (statuse == 0) {
     $('#v2').addClass('ui-flipswitch-active');

 }
 if (statuse == 1) {
     $('#v1').addClass('ui-flipswitch-active');

 }
}   

state();
```

**function which calls php script:**

```
function status () {
        var stats = $("#status").val();
    $.ajax({ url: 'status.php',

         data: {status: stats},
         type: 'post',
         success: function(output) {
                      //alert(output);
                  }
});
}   

status();
setInterval(function(){
    status() // this will run after every 5 seconds
}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try the following to load the proper switchstate on the pageload:

```
<select id="status" name="status" data-role="flipswitch" class="">
  <option id="v1" value="1" <?php if (isset($_POST['status]') && $_POST['status'] == 1) echo 'class="ui-flipswitch-active"'; ?>>ON</option>
  <option id="v2" value="0" <?php if (!isset($_POST['status]') || $_POST['status'] == 0) echo 'class="ui-flipswitch-active"'; ?>>OFF</option>
</select>
```

If you do this afterwards with javascript and the page loads slowly you get a 'flickering' since it takes a while to proces the javascript.

And the javascript:

```
$( "#status" ).change(function() {
    var stats = $("#status").val();
    $.ajax({ url: 'status.php',
     data: {status: stats},
     type: 'post',
     success: function(output) {
                  //alert(output);
              }
    });
});
```

This way when the change event of the select is triggered, it starts the ajax query. Make sure the php script has the session_start(); Otherwise it probably won't work.